# Problems plotting with gnu-apl on OSX

Tags: macos, gnuplot, gnu-apl

I recently installed and tested [gnu-apl](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/) os OSX Catalina with `brew install gnu-apl`

It works well, I'm following the books abstract-algebra and I can do all the exercises. But when I try to plot I allways get:

```
        ⎕PLOT 0 1 ¯1 2 ¯2 3 ¯3
SYNTAX ERROR+
      ⎕PLOT 0 1 ¯1 2 ¯2 3 ¯3
      ^
```

from console and also inside emacs, I need to install gnu-apl from the tarball? I need to link gnuplot library? or simply plots doesn't work in OSX

Comment: Do you have gnuplot installed on your Mac and tested it from terminal to see it is working? Macs have no problem with gnuplot. Really easy to install with [homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Comment: @DanSp, thanks for your reply, I have gnuplot 5.2 and is working well